# Download Excel File from Server has been corrupted - PHP

Tags: php, excel, download

I have a problem about downloading Excel file from server.

the excel file was already saved on the server and I downloaded it using the code below.

```
if(file_exists($reportPath)){
    //content type
    header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    //open/save dialog box
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$dirFile[count($dirFile)-1]);
    //read from server and write to buffer
    readfile($reportPath);
}
```

But the downloaded file was corrupted.

I'm pretty sure that the file saved on the server is not corrupted since I have get it manually from the server to my local desktop.

Meaning, the data has been corrupted on the fly.

Please help, thank you, I'm using PHP

[image: this is the file after downloaded]

Comment: please also note that my code was okay on our server, but not functioning well on another server

Answer (score 1):

Can you try these headers?

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$dirFile[count($dirFile)-1].'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
```

And see if it's working... Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Download script should be separate file. Actually you should not print out anything in this script

```
//Add below to download the text file created
$filename = $file; //name of the file
$filepath = $file; //location of the file. I have put $file since your file is create on the same folder where this script is
header("Cache-control: private");
header("Content-type: application/force-download");
header("Content-transfer-encoding: binary\n");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filepath));
readfile($filepath);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $fileName = "data.xls";
    $object_writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($object, 'Excel5');
    ob_end_clean();
    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=' . $fileName);
    $object_writer->save('php://output');
```

use ob_end_clean() to clear the output buffer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what fixed my issue :

- adding `ob_end_clean` funct after the save.
- adding `exit` at the end of the script.